# Is there an "install without bloatware" option for Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation

I think Linux is mostly only used in VMs nowadays (apart from the big server side). When I start from scratch with my Dev VM, it always annoys me that I have to manually uninstall all the (for me at that point) useless applications. I need git, an IDE, a web browser and some other tools, but not LibreOffice, Rhythmbox and all the other apps that take a notable part of the space.

There is an option to encrypt the hard disk right from the start and it doesn't even work (at least on 17.04). An option like installing only the "core" should be so much easier to implement and would bring a huge improvement to the workflow of a lot of devs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most Ubuntu flavours at 18.04 now support a "minimal" install option.  This would install a browser and a small number of system utilities but most of the apps would be removed.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You should try installation from [netboot](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/) mini.iso and use installed system everywhere where you need - in VM, on server or on desktop.

You can select software with `tasksel` here (including manual package selection).

---

Note: do not use `tasksel` to remove packages from the system (see [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1051440/66509) for details)!