# Every app in my Xubuntu 18.04 deleted by Tasksel. Please Help

Tags: boot, apt, software-installation, samba, tasksel

I tried to remove `samba-server` with this command (`sudo tasksel remove samba-server`) and every app even the system apps are deleted and now xubuntu is stuck at boot, just showing loading. What should I do?

Did `tasksel` deleted my files too?

Comment: Do you mean tasksel?

Comment: Yes my mistake, its 'Tasksel'

Comment: I just tried this in a virtual machine and it did just what you described. Wow! That's a bomb waiting to go off.

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to reinstall the system.  I don't think it deleted your files though.

Comment: But why this happened I just tried to remov Samba-server and Tasksel wiped my whole system

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**TL;DR - it is a serious bug, do not use tasksel for removing things!**

## Analysis

Below is available options of `tasksel`:

```
$ tasksel --help
Unknown option: help
Usage:
tasksel install <task>...
tasksel remove <task>...
tasksel [options]
    -t, --test          test mode; don't really do anything
        --new-install   automatically install some tasks
        --list-tasks    list tasks that would be displayed and exit
        --task-packages list available packages in a task
        --task-desc     returns the description of a task
```

Samba task is named as `samba-server` as you wrote:

```
$ tasksel --list-tasks | grep -i Samba
u samba-server  Samba file server
```

It consists of only one package:

```
$ tasksel --task-packages samba-server
samba-server^
```

If we try to simulate uninstall - we get the following line:

```
$ sudo tasksel --test remove samba-server
debconf-apt-progress -- apt-get -q -y \
-o APT::Install-Recommends=true \
-o APT::Get::AutomaticRemove=true -o APT::Acquire::Retries=3 \ 
install samba-server^-
```

(in the line above the last hyphen `-` cause problems).

What I did:

1. Booted Ubuntu 18.04 LTS clean VM, installed `tasksel` with `sudo apt-get install tasksel`
2. Installed Samba with `sudo tasksel install samba-server`
3. Ran `sudo tasksel remove samba-server`
4. Rebooted and got broken system on next boot

## Fix the system

Then I tried to repair the system:

1. We need to boot in *Recovery mode* (click <kbd>Shift</kbd> on boot, in GRUB select *Advanced options for Ubuntu*, select *Ubuntu, with Linux ... (recovery mode)*)
2. Select `resume     Resume normal boot` to access login shell
3. Open first console #1 with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> then login
4. If you do not have internet - check Ethernet interface name and run DHCP-client manually on it:

   ```
   ifconfig -a # got enp0s3
   sudo dhclient enp0s3
   ```
5. Reinstall `xubuntu-desktop` meta-package to the system:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
   ```
6. After reboot I can access the system.

## Conclusion

So it seems that it is a serious bug - I have found some with almost same symptoms:

- [bug 574287 reported on on 2010-05-03 - "tasksel: forcefully removes packages when tasks overlap"](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tasksel/+bug/574287)
- [bug 1338223 reported on 2014-07-06 - "Tasksel has deleted all my data!"](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tasksel/+bug/1338223).

Also I have filed new [bug 1779645 "Critical bug in tasksel: `tasksel remove task-name` removes whole system"](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tasksel/+bug/1779645)

### What to do?

#### Do not use `tasksel` for removing things at least on 16.04 LTS,  18.04 LTS and 20.04 LTS.

Comment: Thank you so much! Using ```tasksel``` broke my Ubuntu. Will never use it again.

Comment: This is still the case in 20.04 :|. Don't use tasksel in ubuntu.