# Removing KDE using tasksel broke my Ubuntu installation

Tags: boot, gnome, kubuntu, kde, tasksel

After upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04 I couldn't get used to Gnome and decided to try out KDE Plasma. After installing KDE and playing around a bit I decided to move back to Gnome as I thought it's the lesser of two evils.

I also wanted to get rid of the Kubuntu splash screen and Plasma as such and followed someone's advice and removed the Kubuntu desktop using **tasksel** (I was using Gnome while doing it).
During the process I saw that all of my software is getting removed one after another and suddenly the DE wasn't usable at all. After rebooting there was no GUI and I could only access the terminal. Unfortunately, it wasn't possible for me to install ANYTHING as it always returned a "missing archive" error.
Even booting from a live CD doesn't work as I only see the background image - no panels, no software, nothing. BTW: Booting from the same live CD on another computer worked perfectly.

Is there any way I can repair my ubuntu installation? I want at least to be able to copy my files from the HDD and save some configurations.

Thanks

Comment: Use the command line to do the copy then for errors you spoke you need to be more specific

Comment: "Is there any way I can repair my ubuntu installation?" When it is software related always; hardware related might be permanent ;) But you will need to give us something to go on: you got errors, we need that actual text. "I could only access the terminal. " is enough to copy data to an usb stick so do that 1st. " I want at least to be able to copy my files from the HDD and save some configurations." And next time: it is common sense to make a backup FIRST before messing with your system.  Tasks to do: Make a backup from command line, confirm you have a backup and then reinstall.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Every app in my Xubuntu 18.04 deleted by Tasksel. Please Help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051022/every-app-in-my-xubuntu-18-04-deleted-by-tasksel-please-help). Verdict: do not use `tasksel` for removing packages. But you can fix your system by `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-minimal ubuntu-desktop` (change last to desired desktop).