# Uninstall kubuntu-desktop from ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu

I've installed kubuntu desktop on ubuntu 18.04 with tasksel. How can I uninstall it?

Comment: **Do not use `tasksel` for uninstalling things!!!** [It will break your system!](https://askubuntu.com/a/1051440/66509). Use `aptitude` or Synaptic instead.

Comment: @N0rbert can you provide some info on how you solved this using aptitude or synaptic as answer?

Answer (score 8):

If you installed it via `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop` you can uninstall it by

```
sudo apt-get remove kubuntu-desktop --autoremove
```

To be safe, run the reconfigure on your login manager.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

After that, you might need to reboot your machine.

Comment: I've installed kubuntu desktop with tasksel `sudo tasksel install kubuntu-desktop`

Comment: @AFS could you find any solution without breaking the whole system?

Comment: @AFS I'm running  `sudo tasksel remove kubuntu-desktop` now. I'll update this comment if it worked. If not, it means my laptop exploded

Comment: No wonder @JulesColle didn't came back, I tried the same and I barely got my system back to semi working state - can't install newer kernels as they don't boot :/

Comment: DO NOT RUN THIS! `sudo tasksel remove kubuntu-desktop`. It uninstalls EVERYTHING. The only way I found to fix this was to reinstall Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Synaptic as mentioned by @N0rbert, (with completely remove option) was the only way to fully remove all traces of Kubuntu.  Everything worked perfectly.