# Have ran tasksel to remove some stuff on fresh 18.10, got "update-initramfs: failed for..." error

Tags: package-management, 18.10, tasksel

Have ran `tasksel` to remove some unneeded stuff on fresh Ubuntu 18.10 VM and got the following errors:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.131ubuntu15) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.131ubuntu15) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.18.0-10-generic
W: plymouth module (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/plymouth//.so) missing, skipping that theme.
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/plymouth failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.18.0-10-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What should I do to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to determine which `plymouth`-related packages were installed

```
$ dpkg -l | grep plymouth
ii  libplymouth4:amd64                    0.9.3-1ubuntu10                    amd64        graphical boot animation and logger - shared libraries
ii  plymouth                              0.9.3-1ubuntu10                    amd64        boot animation, logger and I/O multiplexer
rc  plymouth-theme-ubuntu-mate-logo       18.10.1                            all          graphical boot animation and logger - ubuntu-mate-logo theme
rc  plymouth-theme-ubuntu-mate-text       18.10.1                            all          graphical boot animation and logger - ubuntu-mate-text theme
ii  plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text            0.9.3-1ubuntu10                    amd64        boot animation, logger and I/O multiplexer - ubuntu text theme
```

and then reinstall them:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall $(dpkg -l | grep plymouth | awk '{print $2}')
```

And voila, problem fixed:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

#### So this example again demonstrates that [`tasksel` should not be used for removing packages on all modern Ubuntu versions!](https://askubuntu.com/a/1051440/66509)