# Deleted DE and I have no internet

Tags: networking, 18.04, kubuntu, kde, desktop-environments

I wanted to ditch GNOME DE and install KDE Plasma (more likely Kubuntu), I did it with `tasksel` but I fell asleep beacuse it took so much and when I woke up my laptop was turned off.  When I booted it the DE woudln't load, so I switched to other desktop (Ctrl + Alt + F2) I uninstalled KDE, and when I rebooted of course it redirected me to tty1 with no DE.

The problem is that I have no internet interface, I'm in loopback, I connected it with wired ethernet and there is no amber light blinking, just the status light that i have something in the port.  I tried to enable networking with recovery and still nothing.

How can I activate networking and finally install KDE Plasma correctly?

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: @N0rbert i did tried sudo apt-get install network-manager and it says that can't fetch it

Comment: Try to follow **Fix the system** part from [duplicate question](https://askubuntu.com/a/1051440/66509).

Comment: @N0rbert i still can't enable the internet :/

Comment: I'm sorry it was actually my router, I forgot that I have a broken port, everything works now thank you so much

Comment: It is great, that you have fixed your issue :)