# How to install minimal but functional MATE DE from network boot mini.iso?

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, 20.04, mate, ubuntu-mate

Let's consider that we have downloaded [network boot mini.iso](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/) (real Ubuntu version does not matter, but LTS is better).

How should I install minimal but functional MATE Desktop Environment from it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options here:

- Select *Ubuntu MATE minimal desktop* on package/task selection page.
- Install minimal system and then install all needed packages with `tasksel`:

  ```
  sudo tasksel install ubuntu-mate-core
  ```

The resulting system will be small (about 4 Gb), but functional.
You can then adjust this basement to suite your needs.

Notes:

1. if you have at least 8.6 Gb of disk space - you can use official [Ubuntu MATE installer](http://ubuntu-mate.org/download/) and select *minimal installation* in it.
2. if you are interested in installing the full MATE DE - it is installable from other *task* package named `ubuntu-mate-desktop^` - see [my other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1160532/66509).
3. do not use `tasksel` to remove packages from the system (see [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1051440/66509) for details)!

Comment: Tasksel in Ubuntu 22.04.1 has no `ubuntu-mate-desktop` nor `ubuntu-mate-core`.
`tasksel install ubuntu-mate-desktop` does nothing.
`tasksel --list-tasks` shows only `mate-desktop` (and others unrelated).
_tasksel 3.68ubuntu2_