# How to correctly install MATE desktop environment on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and newer versions?

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, mate, ubuntu-mate, 21.10

I have just installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS from network boot mini.iso. I want to install fully-functional MATE DE to it.

How should I install it correctly to look like Ubuntu MATE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to install special *task* package with one of two methods:

- with `tasksel`:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install tasksel
  sudo tasksel install ubuntu-mate-desktop
  ```
- with APT:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-desktop^
  ```

And then use the full power power and enjoy the beauty of MATE DE.

---

Notes:

1. if you are interested in installing the minimal MATE DE - it is installable from other *task* package named `ubuntu-mate-core^` - see [my other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1107035/66509).
2. do not use `tasksel` to remove packages from the system (see [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1051440/66509) for details)!

Comment: What is the purpose of installing and using `tasksel` if you can do it with `apt` alone?